# For loop Failed

Tags: lua, roblox

**I have been trying to make a Roblox sword fight game (my first roblox game).**
I found some syntax problems in my code but fixing them didn't fix this issue. I have been going over my code and nothing really seems to work.
Here's the 15th to the 83rd line of code becuase the comments have told me the problem is before the for loop (Before the 15th line are just variables)

```
    --Game Loop

while true do

    Status.Value = "Waiting for enough players"

    repeat wait(1) until game.Players.NumPlayers >= 2

    Status.Value = "Intermission"

    wait(10)

    local plrs = {}

    for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        if player then  
            table.insert(plrs,player) -- Add each player into plrs table
        end
    end

    wait(2)

    local AvailableMaps = MapsFolder:GetChildren()

    local ChosenMap = AvailableMaps[math.random(1,#AvailableMaps)]

    Status.Value = ChosenMap.Name.." Chosen"

    local ClonedMap = ChosenMap:Clone()
    ClonedMap.Parent = workspace

    --Teleport players to the map

    local SpawnPoints = ClonedMap:FindChild("SpawnPoints")

    if not SpawnPoints then
        print("Spawnpoints not found!")
    end

    local AvailableSpawnPoints = SpawnPoints:GetChildren

    for i, player in pairs(plrs) do
        if player then
            character = player.Character

            if character then
                -- Teleport them

                character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame = AvailableSpawnPoints[1].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,10,0)
                table.remove(AvailableSpawnPoints,1)


                -- Give them a Sword

                local Sword = ServerStorage.Sword:Clone()
                Sword.Parent = player.Backpack

                local GameTag = Instance.new("BoolValue")
                GameTag.Name = "GameTag"
                GameTag.Parent = player.Character

            else
                -- There is no character
                if not player then
                    table.remove(plrs,i)
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Here's the error:
19:30:03.021 - ServerScriptService.Main Script:56: Expected '(', '{' or , got 'for'
Help me out fellow gamers

Comment: You have `local.Sword` and want `local Sword`, at a minimum. That doesn't fix the error you've included in your post, though; that error is somewhere else. Indicating which line is like 56 would be helpful.

Comment: If the interpreter expects one thing and gets another, the mistake must be at some point before it detects the error. IOW, there's probably nothing wrong with this `for` loop. Look at earlier statements.

Answer (score 1):

@luther's comment is absolutely right. The line right above the for loop has a syntax error. `SpawnPoints:GetChildren` is a function call, and you forgot to add the parentheses.

```
local AvailableSpawnPoints = SpawnPoints:GetChildren()
```